# Wrong Answer while implementing queues -reference binding to null pointer of type

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, c++14

I was solving this problem on codeforces : [Lose it!](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1176/C) when I submitted and got a WA(wrong answer) on test case 6.

**The Problem**: Remove minimal number of elements from an array such that the array is composed of `{4,8,15,16,23,42}` and in order. To read the problem in detail, please refer to the link.

**My Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define rep(i,a,b) for(auto (i)=a;i<b;i++)
#define list(i,N) for(auto (i)=0;i<N;i++)

typedef long long ll;

int indexOf(int element, int array[], int N){
    list(i,N){
        if(array[i]==element) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

    int N; cin >> N;
    int array[N];
    int counter = 0;
    int elements[6] = {4,8,15,16,23,42};
    list(i,N){ cin >> array[i]; }
    int len = N;
    int rem = len%6;
    int quo = len/6;
    //an array of queues
    queue<int> removals[quo];
    //initialize the removals array
    list(i,quo){ list(j,6) removals[i].push(elements[j]); }

    list(i,len){
        int tops[quo];
        list(j,quo){
            if(removals[j].empty()) tops[j] = -10;
            else tops[j] = removals[j].front(); 
        }
        int idx = indexOf(array[i],tops,quo);

        if(idx==-1){ counter++; /*cout << "Incrementing Counter at " << i << "!\n";*/ }
        else removals[idx].pop();
    }

    cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

**Approach**: 
Basically, what I am doing is to maintain an array of queues. As we iterate through the elements in the array, we check which queue has the element on top and pop it. If not found on the top of any queue, increase the `counter` by 1.

**The Problem:**
So, I submitted my code and found out that it failed on: 
100
4 42 23 23 8 42 16 23 42 16 42 8 4 23 4 4 23 42 16 42 23 23 23 42 4 42 8 8 16 23 15 23 16 4 42 15 15 23 16 15 16 4 4 15 23 42 42 15 8 23 8 23 4 15 16 15 42 8 23 16 15 42 23 8 4 16 15 16 23 16 16 4 23 16 8 23 16 15 23 4 4 8 15 4 4 15 8 23 23 4 4 8 8 4 42 15 4 4 42 16
giving the answer of `41` instead of the correct answer `64`. I tried to find out where the error is, but unforunately, the test size is too long. What is possibly wrong in this code?

***What it says***

```
Diagnostics detected issues [cpp.clang++-diagnose]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\deque:329:10: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const long long'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\deque:329:10 in
```

The above is what the diagnostics say. I checked online for what it meant, and it is something related to the size of a vector but I have not used vectors anywhere. Moreover, if there was a big fault, I would not have passes test cases 1-5. I think there is an error directly related to the above test cases.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to Igor Tandetnik, the diagnostics is now gone. I had forgotten to put an else statement. But still, my code gets WA. Any suggestions?

Comment: I advice using `assert` statements whenever you are trying to access an array element by index. Dynamic arrays are not valid in C++. Use `std::vector` instead and `std::vector::at(i)` instead of `[i]`, it will check access range, `assert` is not needed.

Comment: Off the top  - you check for `removals[j].empty()`, but then go ahead and access `removals[j].front()` anyway. That exhibits undefined behavior if the queue is in fact empty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. I forgot the else statement but my code still gives WA as answer is 64 but my code gives 41. Is there something I am missing? Thanks.